# Give an SKNode its own physics

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, physics, skspritenode

Is there a way to give an SKNode its own physics? I have an SKShapeNode call "backGround" which I use for the parent node of most of my other nodes. I am constantly moving "background" to the left, to give the illusion that the player is moving forward. However, one of the objects that has "backGround" as a parent node is a pin with a rope hanging from it. When background accelerates to the left, is there a way to make it so the rope doesn't swing back and forth, as ropes tend to do when accelerating or decelerating?

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
func createRopeNode(pos: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode{
    let ropeNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    ropeNode.size = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    ropeNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ropeNode.size)
    ropeNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ropeNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    ropeNode.alpha = 1
    ropeNode.position = CGPoint(x: pos.x + 0, y: pos.y)
    ropeNode.name = "RopePiece"
    let text = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RopeTexture")
    ropeNode.zPosition = -5
    text.runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(atan2(-dx!, dy!), duration: 0))
    ropeNode.addChild(text)
    return ropeNode
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if (!playerIsConnected){
        playerIsConnected = true
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        dx = pin.position.x - playerPoint!.x
        dy = pin.position.y - playerPoint!.y
        let length = sqrt(pow(dx!, 2) + pow(dy!, 2))
        let distanceBetweenRopeNodes = 5
        let numberOfPieces = Int(length)/distanceBetweenRopeNodes
        var ropeNodes = [SKSpriteNode]()

        //adds the pieces to the array at respective locations
        for var index = 0; index < numberOfPieces; ++index{
            let point = CGPoint(x: pin.position.x + CGFloat((index) * distanceBetweenRopeNodes) * sin(atan2(dy!, -dx!) + 1.5707), y: pin.position.y + CGFloat((index) * distanceBetweenRopeNodes) * cos(atan2(dy!, -dx!) + 1.5707))
            let piece = createRopeNode(point)
            ropeNodes.append(piece)
            world.addChild(ropeNodes[index])
        }
        let firstJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(ropeNodes[0].physicsBody, bodyB: pin.physicsBody, anchor:
            CGPoint(x: (ropeNodes[0].position.x + pin.position.x)/2, y: (ropeNodes[0].position.y + pin.position.y)/2))
        firstJoint.frictionTorque = 1
        self.physicsWorld.addJoint(firstJoint)
        for var i = 1; i < ropeNodes.count; ++i{
            let nodeA = ropeNodes[i - 1]
            let nodeB = ropeNodes[i]
            let middlePoint = CGPoint(x: (nodeA.position.x + nodeB.position.x)/2, y: (nodeA.position.y + nodeB.position.y)/2)
            let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(nodeA.physicsBody, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody, anchor: middlePoint)
            joint.frictionTorque = 0.1
            self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
        }
        finalJoint?.frictionTorque = 1
        finalJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(ropeNodes[ropeNodes.count - 1].physicsBody, bodyB: player.physicsBody, anchor:
            CGPoint(x: (ropeNodes[ropeNodes.count - 1].position.x + playerPoint!.x)/2, y: (ropeNodes[ropeNodes.count - 1].position.y + playerPoint!.y)/2))
        self.physicsWorld.addJoint(finalJoint!)
        }
    }
    else{
        physicsWorld.removeJoint(finalJoint!)
        playerIsConnected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move the `world` node, everything should move without accelerating or decelerating.

Comment: @0x141E I created my rope by using a series of SKJointPins that I added to the scene by `self.PhysicsWorld.addJoint(myJoint)`. Wouldn't that cause the rope to accelerate when "world" accelerates?

Comment: Does your world change speed over time or move with a constant speed?

Comment: @0x141E it changes speed. It moves to the left at just the right speed so that its child node known as "player" appears to stay in the middle of the screen

Comment: How are you moving the world? With a force/impulse or by changing its position directly?

Comment: @0x141E I am moving it directly

Comment: Moving the world shouldn't have any effect on the physics bodies.

Comment: Even if there are physics joints added to the scene?

Comment: Did you attach the rope to the scene's physics body?

Comment: Well to create the for loop, I looked through every link of my chain/rope and said world.addChild(ropeNode).

Comment: But the joints themselves that held all the ropeNodes together were added to the scene by using "self"

Comment: You mean the physicsWorld

Comment: Yes, I mean I added my physicsJoints to self.physicsworld

Comment: What are you attaching the end of the rope to?

Comment: I added my code to the question. Maybe that should clear some things up

Comment: Ok what is pin attached to?

Comment: @0x141E the pin is also a child of world

Comment: If pin is not dynamic and a child of the world, then the rope shouldn't swing when you move the world.

Comment: @0x141E Ok, then maybe there's something else going on. I could have sworn the rope was swinging when the world node was accelerating...

Comment: Maybe when you detach the player, the rope swings in the other direction?

Comment: @0x141E No, its pretty obvious. Its a little hard to explain without a visual example, but to put it in my best words, the pin shot away to the left so fast that the ropeNodes couldn't catch up and started to visually separate. They still held together, but it looked really weird.

Comment: Ok I suggest you loop over all nodes in the world and move the ones with a dynamic physics body. You should move the node by the same amount that the world moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor points are what you are looking for.  Move the anchor point of the scene to only move the "camera" of the scene (what is displayed onscreen).  This will not jostle the pin and rope.  Keep in mind that the anchor point is on a slightly different scale from the scene.

Where the width of the scene could be 1024, the "width" of the of the anchor point for one scene length is 1 (basically counting as one width of the node).  Same for the height, where it could be 768, the "height" would still be 1 in the anchor point coordinate space.  So to move half a screen width, move the anchor point 0.5

The anchor point is a `CGPoint`, so you can go vertically as well.  Here's a quick example:

```
var xValue : Float = 0.75
var yValue : Float = 0.0
self.scene?.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);
```

And for further reading, [here's a link to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW36) on anchor points for sprites.

Comment: Updated my answer for Swift, just noticed that you were using that language.  Sorry about that!